# Keep same icon size with flex box responsive

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a problem with my tuner, I try to keep the same size arrow, but when I reduce the resolution the arrow becomes smaller

```
<div className="shadow rounded my-5">
            <div onClick={() => toggle(index)} key={index} className="bg-[#8e9fbc] rounded text-white font-bold flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer p-5">
        <span>{item.question}</span>
        {clicked === index ? (<ChevronDownIcon className="w-6 "/>) :<ChevronRightIcon className="w-6  "/>}
        
        </div>
       {clicked === index ? (<div className="p-5"> {item.reponse}</div>) : null} </div>
```

[image]

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply apply `flex-shrink: 0;` to the icons, this prevent them from getting smaller.

Note that you should have width for those icons.

Comment: The Tailwind utility class is `shrink-0`.